# How to remove default modules on single event page on Modern Events Calendar

Tags: custom-post-types

I can edit the CPT "events" added by the Modern Events Calendar plugin. However, I cannot get rid of the default modules that are loaded in the frontend after creating a new event.

Can anyone help me with a piece of code to disable them?

I still want to use the custom fields in the back-end as it helps set up event listings but I want to be in full control of the single event page layout.

thanks a ton to anyone who can help.

Kind regards
Will

Comment: what do you name "default modules" ? edit your question to add more details, images, etc.

Comment: This is a specific plugin question, which should be directed towards the plugin developer e.g. in the WordPress plugin support forum or their own website. Hint: you need to overwrite the template of the single-page template of the calendar. Browse the docs to get more info.

Comment: Thank you both for your prompt reply, I will try to find help from the plugin developer.